# Block access to port directly but allow access through subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, debian-jessie

I've recently started using an Elastic search, Logstash and Kibana to help visualize the logs on my server.

This is working out great, but the only catch is that this is all publicly accessible by accessing them through their ports on my server. e.g `example.com:9200` or `example.com:5601`.

I've found out a way to restrict elastic search to local traffic only, but I need a way to restrict public access to Kibana.

I want to keep it public, so that I can access it but put it in front of some basic authentication using `htaccess`. I have successfully implemented this, so that if I navigate to `kibana.example.com` it will ask me for a username and password before going through. However I can still access it directly using `example.com:5601` and not be asked for authentication.

Looking around, it seems that iptables are the way to go with this. I tried using `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5601 -j DROP` and this does block all access to the port, but it also blocks the traffic I want to allow when directing through `kibana.example.com`.

How can I modify the rule above to allow access through `kibana.example.com` but block access when you try to go to the port directly?

My server runs Debain Jessie and I am using Apache 2.2 as my web server.

Comment: Just changing the listening IP for Kibana to be the local loopback adapter.

Comment: @GregL how do you do that?

Comment: I'd suggest you read the [manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html) for Kibana, because all the answers you seek are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by using this `iptable` rule:

`iptables -A INPUT ! -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5601 -j DROP`

It accepts all connections to port 5601 from localhost (which was done through my Apache proxy) and drops all other connections.